# Extract data by day from SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, timestamp, datediff

I need to get all the values from a SQL Server database by day (24 hours). I have timestamps column in `TestAllData` table and I want to select the data which only corresponds to a specific day.

For instance, there are timestamps of `DateTime` type like `'2019-03-19 12:26:03.002', '2019-03-19 17:31:09.024'` and `'2019-04-10 14:45:12.015'` so I want to load the data for the day `2019-03-19` and separately for the day `2019-04-10`. Basically, it is needed to get DateTime values with the same date.

Is this possible to use some functions like `DatePart` or `DateDiff` for that?

And how can I solve such problem overall?

As in this case, I do not know the exact difference in hours between a timestamp and the end of the day (because there are various timestamps for 1 day) and I need to extract the day itself from the timestamp. After that, I need to group the data by days or something like this and get block by block. For example:

'2019-03-19' - 1200 records
'2019-04-10' - 3500 records
'2019-05-12' - 10000 records and so on

**I'm looking for a more generic solution not supplying a timestamp (like '2019-03-19') as a boundary or in a where clause because the problem is not about simply filtering the data by some date!!**

**UPDATE:** In my dataset, I have about 1,000,000 records and more than 100 unique dates. I was thinking about extracting the set of unique dates and then kind of run a query in the loop where the data would be filtered by the provided day. It would look in such a way:

```
select * from TestAllData where dayColumn = '2019-03-19'
select * from TestAllData where dayColumn = '2019-04-10'
select * from TestAllData where dayColumn = '2019-05-12'
...
```

I might use this query in my code, so I may run it in the loop from Scala function. However, I am not sure that in terms of performance it would be ok to run separate unique dates extraction query.

Comment: Sample data, expected results, and your attempts will help here. I would have gone with the answer that Forpas posted (now deleted), but you said it's not as simple as that, so I agree with their comment: "If it is not that simple then why did you ask a simple question?" Give us all the details so that we can help you. Without them we can't, and you're on your own to solve this.

Comment: You don't use functions - you simply use the proper boundaries. Do not allow laziness to lead your development. What is today? It is May 12 2019 7:49am as I type. How do you find all rows for "today"? You use a lower bound of beginning of day (eg., >= '20190512') and the appropriate upper bound  of  beginning of tommorrow (e.g., < '20190513'). Discussed in great detail by Tibor [here](https://karaszi.com/the-ultimate-guide-to-the-datetime-datatypes)

Comment: @SMor boundaries might be a good solution but how can I defined them with dynamically changing timestamps. I just want to run a very generic query without specifying exact timestamp like  '20190512'. So it would be possible to run it without being bound to specific data

Comment: @Larnu I gave him a clear reason why the proposed solution would not work for my case. It is not very nice to create such a toxic environment here when it is simply a discussion of the question.

Comment: I'm not being toxic at all, and had no intention to, Cassie, I'm just stating what we need. We don't have any of those, and so the best we can do if guess, or provide answers that end up being incomplete for your needs. If we have a complete question (an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) then the volunteers using their free time to help you will be able to help you that much more easily, and you'll get an answer that much quicker. it's of benefit to everyone.

Comment: @Larnu You are not being toxic. On the contrary, thanks for stating the problem. I mean the deleted answer and comment.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on whether you want to be able to work with all the dates (rather than just a subset), one of the easiest ways to achieve this is with a cast:

```
;with cte as (SELECT cast(my_datetime as date) as my_date, * from TestAllData)
SELECT * FROM cte where my_date = '2019-02-14'
```

Note when casting datetime to date, times are truncated, ie just the date part is extracted.

As I say though, whether this is efficient, depends on your needs, as all datetime values from all records will be cast to date, before the data is filtered.  If you want to select several dates (as opposed to just one or two), however, it may prove overall quicker, as it reads the whole table once and then gives you a column upon which you can much more efficiently filter.

If this is a permanent requirement, though, I would probably use a persisted computed column, which effectively would mean that the casting is done once initially and then only again if the corresponding value changed. For a large table I would also strongly consider an index on the computed column.